# SwiftyJson Parsing Issue When Parsing from a Push Notification

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

## Question on Parsing JSON using Swifty JSON

This is **SwiftyJSON* question: I attempted to parse some JSON coming in from a push notification but I couldn't seem to get it to individual values

```
if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {
print("before")
print(json["data"].stringValue)   
print ("after")
}
```

### and I end up with console output of

```
before

{
   "apiKey":{
      "data":{
         "user_id":8,
         "id":75,
         "secret":"G4UgMXXXXnt0bviGjNHCPRY4nYjuvXMrEkaU2dxqOC9j7XiIy4uS1TNLxv4Kev7w"
      }
   },
   "verified":true,
   "loneWorker":{
      "data":{
         "vehicle_make":null,
         "gender":null,
         "mobile":"+447900007213",
         "vehicle_model":null,
         "hair_colour":null,
         "distinguishing_features":null,
         "firebase_token":"dsMGqAn57eo:APA91bHcE_8hoCQ9qgJfpr4b6yDrUkkkeJL7oGx-410v7hKyZfgBkcvROHevTmojJ6CvQrspDOvvXnXo9psTRKdnlQAEYzdvBE8OtsxHf-3JRmDRbJCiTrsVowDgQ5FeN7QQaEfMbFH",
         "vehicle_colour":null,
         "vrm":null,
         "arc":{
            "data":{
               "prealert_sms_number":"+447506000094",
               "sos_sms_number":"+44750000894",
               "id":1,
               "sos_call_number":"+447500000094"
            }
         },
         "build":null,
         "dob":null,
         "duress_word":null,
         "name":"Stevan ",
         "id":8,
         "preexisting_conditions":null,
         "email":"xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
         "height":null
      }
   }
}

after
```

but if I try to do: 
    `print(json["data"]["apiKey"]["secret"].stringValue)` 
I get nothing.

I've a mental block with this and can't solve parsing this with SwiftyJSON or any other normal way...

[EDIT: Thankfully, I worked out the answer to this question which you may see in the comments below. These days I now like `Codable` as a good modern alternative].

Comment: A tip: Do it piece by piece. Because when you write `json["data"]["apiKey"]["secret"].stringValue` you don't know where it started "failing". So `json["data"]`, then `json["data"]["apiKey"]`, then `json["data"]["apiKey"]["secret"]` and that's the one failing. But you'll see that you need to do a `["data"]` after `["apiKey"]`.

Comment: Because of the unusual formatting of my input, I had to retrieve the json["data"] and parse it from string to json again like this:            if let json = try? JSON(data: data) {


                let parsedJSON: AnyObject? = (json["data"].stringValue).parseJSONString  // go down a level by passing in json["data"].stringValue
                
                
                let swifyJSON = JSON(parsedJSON) // make that level SwiftyJSON ready}

Comment: extension String{ var parseJSONString: AnyObject?{let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
 if let jsonData = data { do { let message = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options:.mutableContainers)
if let jsonResult = message as? NSMutableArray { return jsonResult //Will return the json array output} else if let jsonResult = message as? NSMutableDictionary { return jsonResult //Will return the json dictionary output } else {return nil } } catch let error as NSError { print("An error occurred: \(error)") return nil }}else { return nil }}}

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the value in a wrong way.
You have to access the value with `json["data"]["apiKey"]["data"]["secret"].stringValue`.